# How to loop through a list of self referencing entity in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an entity as below

```
public class Entity{
    ....
    private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    ....
    //Other fields with its setters and getters
}
```

How do I display all the `entities` using Thymeleaf. I've just started using thymeleaf and I tried searching where ever I could.

Comment: and what did you tried?

Comment: try reading the thymeleaf [tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it from the java side.  Something like this for example:

JAVA

```
public class Entity{
    private List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Entity> getAllEntities() {
        List<Entity> all = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Entity e: entities) {
            all.add(this);
            all.addAll(e.getAllEntities())
        }

        return all;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div th:each="entity: ${entities.allEntities}">
     <span th:text="${entity.someProperty}" />
</div>
```

It may be possible by including a fragment as well -- but I'm not sure it's possible to have a thyme leaf fragment include itself.